# Cut string obtained with Javascript inside hyperlink

Tags: javascript

I made a bookmark that users can add and it sends them to my site capturing the referrer.

```
<a href="javascript:location='http://www.chusmix.com/tests/?ref='+escape(location.href);" onclick="alert('Drag it, not click it!');return false;"> Bookmark </a>
```

My problem is that for some reason the location.href part instead of printing http:// it prints: "http%3A//". I want to remove it and get just the domain.com

I have a similar code that maybe could be useful but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement it inside HTML.

```
// Function to clean url

    function cleanURL(url)
    {
        if(url.match(/http:\/\//))
        {
            url = url.substring(7);
        }
        if(url.match(/^www\./))
        {
            url = url.substring(4);
        }

        url = "www.chusmix.com/tests/?ref=www." + url;

        return url;
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please don't do this. No offense, but if a user would drag this link to his browsers toolbar as a bookmark, this would act kind of spyware. The `location.href` you `escape` (which is obsolete btw, you should use `encodeURIComponent()`), will be evaluated at **runtime**, i.e. if a user clicks this bookmark, the `location.href` of the page he is **currently viewing** would be sent, which is most likely **not** the same page as at the time he bookmarked one of your pages.

Comment: I'm not storing it or anything, I just need to know where he comes from because what is going to be displayed depends on where he comes from.

Comment: I need to send the page he is currently viewing not the one where he created the bookmark. Could using location.ref and escape cause me problems? What would be the proper method to do it?

Comment: As of now the bookmark is working as it should, I just want to remove the "http%3A//" so it's cleaner!

Comment: Yes, using `location.href` can cause privacy problems, when used in a bookmark. Imagine a user is viewing a page that he definitely wants to keep private to himself. Clicking the bookmark while viewing that private page would expose it to your website. I doubt all users are aware what they send when clicking such bookmark, as there was another page context active the time dragging the link into the toolbar.

Comment: I understand, but in this case they are aware of what they are doing. The site simply takes other urls and transforms them into fake sites that scare you after a while. So the user is totally aware what he is doing, he picks the site he wants to transform and then click on the bookmark to do it. www.linkimprov.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like already stated in my comment:

**Be aware** that this kind of bookmarking **may harm users privacy**, so please inform them accordingly.

That being said:

First, please use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `escape()`, since `escape()` is deprecated since [ECMAScript-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) v3.

Second, to get rid of the "http%3A//" do **not** use `location.href`, but assemble the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) properties `host`, `pathname`, `search` and `hash` instead:

```
encodeURIComponent(location.host + location.pathname + location.search + location.hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, the referrer is sent as a standard field of the HTTP protocol. This technically isn't the answer to your question, but it would be a cleaner and less conspicuous solution to grab that information server-side.

In PHP, for example, you could write:

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

...and then store that in a text file or a database or what-have-you. I can't really tell what your end purpose is, because clicking a bookmark lacks the continuity of browsing that necessitates referrer information (like the way that moving from a search engine or a competitor's website would). They could be coming from a history of zero, from another page on your site or something unrelated altogether.